# Java - JLabel with icon not aligned (going to the right)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlabel

I'm trying to make a deck manager for a card game (Yu-Gi-Oh :D), and for now I only have a table with available cards and a panel that shows the card the user selected in a bigger size and with the card's description.
MVCE:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class SelectedCardPanel extends JPanel{
        private final JLabel cardArea;
        private final JTextArea cardInfo;

        public static void main(String args[]){
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Yu-Gi-Oh!");
                    frame.add(new SelectedCardPanel());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        public SelectedCardPanel(){
            super();

            setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));

            cardArea = new JLabel("                                 ");
            cardArea.setOpaque(true);
            cardArea.setBackground(Color.white);
            cardArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
            cardArea.setSize(cardArea.getPreferredSize());
            cardArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

            cardInfo = new JTextArea();
            cardInfo.setEditable(false);
            cardInfo.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            cardInfo.setLineWrap(true);
            cardInfo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
            cardInfo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

            add(cardArea);
            add(cardInfo);
        }

        public final void setImage(ImageIcon icon){
            cardArea.setIcon(icon);
        }
    }
```

But that's what happens:
[image: deck manager]
In the MVCE:

[image: label to the right]

The cardArea gets to the right, and I don't understand why.

The card I select in the Table goes without problems to the selected card panel.
Why is the JLabel getting to the right?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: *"I don't know if it's OK to ask these two questions at the same post"* Wow! You managed two questions in a post that contained not one single '?'!  ..What were they?

Comment: @AndrewThompson about the JLabel getting to the right and the Table not adding a new row...I thought that as the second wasn't specified on the title it could be a bad way to do it..."I'd like to know how to fix these 2 problems, thanks in advance." hehe I should've actually asked shouldn't I?

Comment: Please narrow it down to ***one*** question.

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry for that, thanks for the guidance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the BoxLayout. I would instead recommend using a `BorderLayout` And get rid of all the `set[Preferred]Sizes`. As for the text area, use the constructor `JTextArea(rows, cols)`. For the columns you can leave at 0, and with BorderLayout, it will stretch to match the width of the image

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SelectCardPanel extends JPanel{
    private final JLabel cardArea;
    private final JTextArea cardInfo;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Yu-Gi-Oh!");
                SelectCardPanel panel = new SelectCardPanel();
                panel.setImage(new ImageIcon(SelectCardPanel.class.getResource("images.jpg")));
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public SelectCardPanel(){
        super();

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));

        cardArea = new JLabel();
        cardArea.setOpaque(true);
        cardArea.setBackground(Color.white);
        //cardArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
        //cardArea.setSize(cardArea.getPreferredSize());
        cardArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        cardInfo = new JTextArea(5, 0);
        cardInfo.setEditable(false);
        cardInfo.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        cardInfo.setLineWrap(true);
        //cardInfo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        cardInfo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        add(cardArea);
        add(cardInfo, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public final void setImage(ImageIcon icon){
        cardArea.setIcon(icon);
    }
}
```